# Discontinuity question

Tags: limits

> $$f(x)=x^2+1\ \ \ if\ \ \ x>2
>         \\=8x\ \ \ if\ \ \ x<2 $$ 
>   Find the discontinuous point.

I thought it is on $x=2$ because when I substitute $2$ into the equations, one get $5$ and another one get $16$. But answer said there is no discontinuity point.

Answer (score 1):

The function is only defined for $x > 2$ and $x < 2$, so $2$ is not a discontinuity point because it does not lie in the domain of definition of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

As written, your function is not defined at $x=2$. So on its domain it is continuous everywhere. You are correct in saying that if, for instance, it was $f(x)=8x$ for $x\geq2$ the function would be discontinuous at 2.

Answer (score 0):

The answer  says it has no point of discontinuity because the function is not defined at $x=2$ . From what you have written it looks like ***the domain of definition of the function is $(-\infty ,2)\cup (2,\infty).$***  And on this region, as you can easily check the function is continuous as both $x^2+1$ and $8x$ are continuous on their respective domains. Their is no ***point of discontinuity*** for $f(x)$ on its domain.